# How to correctly show webcam stream in a WPF application with OpenCvSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv

I'm working with .NET Framework 4.8 and NuGet libraries: `OpenCvSharp4`, `OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win`, `OpenCvSharp4.Windows` and I'm trying to code a simple `WebcamStreaming` class that takes as input a `WPF` `System.Windows.Controls.Image` and exposes some `Start` and `Stop` methods to show the camera output.

I did it, and it works, but there are two things I'm not sure about:

1. **CPU gets very high while streaming**, around 30/40%. I think it is the `VideoCapture` read frames loop, so I put an `await Task.Delay(10)` to free some resources on each cycle and it is working. Now the CPU is always < 10%. But **is this the correct solution**? Am I doing something wrong earlier?
2. When I close the application, I get always this exception: `Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' : 'Transition into COM context 0x12f6648 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)). This is typically because the COM context 0x12f6648 where this RuntimeCallableWrapper was created has been disconnected or it is busy doing something else. Releasing the interfaces from the current COM context (COM context 0x12f6700). This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that all COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are available for context transition, until the application is completely done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components that live inside them.'`. 
   Do you know what is it and what I'm doing wrong?

---

## The code

You can find the whole example on a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/FrancescoBonizzi/WebcamControl-WPF-With-OpenCV) I've created.

The interesting part of the frames fetch loop:

```
_previewTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    using (var frame = new Mat())
    {
        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _videoCapture.Read(frame);

            if (!frame.Empty())
            {
                _lastFrame = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
                var lastFrameBitmapImage = _lastFrame.ToBitmapSource();
                lastFrameBitmapImage.Freeze();

                _imageControlForRendering.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _imageControlForRendering.Source = lastFrameBitmapImage);
                await Task.Delay(10);
            }
        }
    }
}, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

The disposal process (I call it when the application gets closed):

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    if (_videoCapture?.IsDisposed == false)
    {
        _videoCapture?.Dispose();
        _videoCapture = null;
    }
    _lastFrame?.Dispose();
}
```

---

#### Update for the second point

The problem was caused by the fact that the thread in which I was calling `Dispose` wasn't the same thread in which I created `VideoCapture`.

Comment: Without the `Task.Delay`, your loop will acquire and render images as quickly as it can. By definition, it will try and remain as busy as possible, and so will max out one CPU core. If your CPU has 2 cores, this equates to 50% usage. Note that if the frame is empty, your current code will start maxing out the CPU again: I suggest moving the `Task.Delay` out of that `if`

Comment: Thanks, how to choose correctly how much time wait?

Comment: I don't think there's a hard-and-fast answer there. In theory I think you can see how fast the webcam's spitting out frames and match that, but a brief google suggests that's a bit complex. You could just decide that 30fps ought to be good enough for anyone. If you're streaming over a network, you could scale based on bandwidth requirements...

Comment: Thanks for publishing that example on github, it works well. Would it be possible to use it to actually record the video to a file and also include the audio from the webcam (or a separate audio device)?

Comment: Your welcome! I never tried it, if you want to do some tests you can make a pull request :-)